How to calculate RAM available in IAR workbench or Using .map file?
Want to read available RAM from the IAR Project using .map file?
We have assigned 8Mb of RAM and extracting the .data and .bss segment from the .map file and calculating the used RAM. Is that correct way to calculate?
Please let me know if anything else is required.
These below commands are using to extract from the .map file and copied to .csv file
grep -E ".bss|.data|.rodata" file.map | awk '{print $1 "," $2 "," $3,"," $4}' \> space_buf128.csv


Your section list seems very small. What about .stack, .noinit or any user specified sections that might reserving memory?
Newer IAR versions (EWARM 9.20 at least) already generate information of unused addresses in map file. Look for Unused ranges: text to find a table.

Thanks for the response!
there is no .stack and .noinit in .map file.
It has sections like .text, .rodata, .bss and .data
Currently Using EWARM 7.80.
So here I want to calculate total RAM used.
